# Log::Timeline Visualisation in IntelliJ

Tags: raku, commaide

Is the [Log::Timeline Visualization](https://twitter.com/croservices/status/1146458203217104896) also supported with the Comma IDEA Plugin for IntelliJ or is it only part of the standalone Comma IDE? And if it is supported with IntelliJ, are there additional components needed in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is supported through the plugin also. I just tried it with the latest Comma Community plugin by:

1. Creating a new Cro Web Application project (though any Perl 6 project type will work, this just got me something to test without needing to write any code).
2. Creating a run configuration (a Cro one, but again, a normal Perl 6 one would do also).

The Timeline option for this run configuration is then available (for instance, on the Run menu). And here it is running:

[image: Timeline visualizer in IntelliJ]

Note: make sure you have Cro 0.8.1 installed if trying to visualize a Cro web application.